# Calculating the area of groups based on intersect of several shapefiles using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have 5 shapefiles. There are 72 possible groups of 'land cover+top-rock+subrock+soil drainge' in each watershed. I want to get the area of the different groups of 'land cover+top-rock+subrock+soil drainge' in each watershed.

[image]

I have thought about:

1. Intersect the shapefiles.
2. Create a new column named group ='land cover+top-rock+subrock+soil 
   drainge' columns
3. Calculate area of each polygon in the column 'group'

Is there a way to get the area of groups resulting from intersect of several shapefiles at once using ArcPy?

Answer (score 1):

Precisely how you will do this will depend on your license level of ArcGIS for Desktop because, from the [Intersect help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm):

> With ArcGIS for Desktop Basic and Standard licenses, the number of
>   input feature classes or layers is limited to two.

Unless you have Advanced you will need to Intersect using pairs at a time.

In any event I think you should try your workflow, and if it does not produce the result you are expecting then you will be in a good position to show us details of the step where your workflow appears to go astray.